# How to make a UITableViewController subclass respect topLayoutGuide in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

in my app I have a simple `UITableViewController` that's just plain Objective-C code, no .xib or storyboard involved. It represents the contents of one tab in a tab bar.

Since iOS 7 its contents are overlapped by the status bar at the top and tab bar at the bottom.

Using only code, how can I make the table view add space at the top and bottom to align with `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`?

I know about

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
```

but that seems to simply shrink the table view to not intersect the tab bar and to disable the transparency of the tab bar. Instead I'd like the table view to add some padding.

Thanks!

**Update:**

I've also tried explicitly setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `YES`, but that didn't help either (should be the default behavior anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not (yet) supported, at least for programmatically created `UITableViewController`s without an `UINavigationController` that's embedding them.

I checked the position for both layout guides, and at run-time both off-sets read 0 distance from the edges of the screen. Hence `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` won't set the insets correctly.

So now I actually modify my first section header and last section footer manually to add 21 pixels at the top and 50 pixels at the bottom respectively.

Bummer. :-(